# How to create a blank page without any header,footer blocks?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, cms-block

Am creating a cms page for sellers, like `www.mysite.com/seller` with unique nav-bar,footer,header,logo etc..but it all shows under my default theme's header,footer blocks.I planned to show those cms as like new website without any blocks from my store.

1. How to show a cms page header,footer,navbar as like a new domain?

### or

2. Is it only possible by creating sub-domain for my site like
   `seller.mysite.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the "empty" page layout in the "Design" tab of the CMS page:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: works perfect..!!  Am very happy to your damn easy solution..Thank you sir